# Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be two metric spaces with a bijection between them. If $(X,d)$ is complete then can we say $(Y,\rho)$ also complete?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The question arise when I study complete space . We know if there a bijection between two set then their property will same ,is it true for completeness property of a metric space. We know $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ has a bijection and both are complete in usual metric . Is there any other relation between metric d and ρ ?

Comment: You can consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard Euclidean metric for a counterexample.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is in bijection with $\mathbb R$. In fact, there is a homeomorphism between these two!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric space of rationals $\Bbb Q$ equipped with the discrete metric is complete (Cauchy sequences are eventually constant) but the very same set $\Bbb Q$ equipped with the usual euclidean metric its not: moreover they can both be considered as metric subspaces of $\Bbb R$ .

Comment: +1 I prefer this to the answers in the comments, you don't have to know that the rationals are countable, or even that there is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$